# DAO class for Json object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have Json format like this :-

```
{
    "[0].Storage": {
        "telemetryPrefix": ["System_Storage_*", "Storage_*"],
        "uiOrder": 1
    },
    "[1].Network": {
        "telemetryPrefix": ["System_Network_*", "Network_*"],
        "uiOrder": 2
    },
}
```

I want to create DAO class of it. As I am new in Spring unable to figure out proper way of it. Can anyone suggest proper way ? Thanks !

Comment: Are the numbers static and part of the names? Or an indication of position, thus indicating there could be more than just 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following. Make sure you change the names to Java Naming Standards

```
public class 0Storage{
    public ArrayList<String> telemetryPrefix;
    public int uiOrder;
}

public class 1Network{
    public ArrayList<String> telemetryPrefix;
    public int uiOrder;
}

public class Root{
    @JsonProperty("[0].Storage") 
    public 0Storage _0Storage;
    @JsonProperty("[1].Network") 
    public 1Network _1Network;
}
```

There are online tools(like [this](https://freecodegenerators.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo)) you can use for more complex data structures.